# How to target only formatted text in Word document, for a Find and Replace process

Tags: powershell, replace, ms-word, find, wildcard

I would like to edit a Word file using a "Find and Replace" approach (in wildcards mode). I’m exclusively targeting italic and bold characters.
Thus :
"One, *two*, **three**."
Should become:
"One, *two_italic*, **three_bold**."
Here is my script...

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("D:\before.docx")
$objWord.Visible = $true
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection

$Request = @"
FIND,REPLACE
"<[A-Za-z]*>", "^&_italic"
"<[A-Za-z]*>", "^&_bold"
"@ 

$RequestObjs = ConvertFrom-Csv $Request
$FindItalic = $RequestObjs[0]
$FindBold = $RequestObjs[1]

$ReplaceAll = 2
$FindContinue = 1
$MatchCase = $False
$MatchWholeWord = $True
$MatchWildcards = $True
$MatchSoundsLike = $False
$MatchAllWordForms = $False
$Forward = $True
$Wrap = $FindContinue
$Format = $True

function findAndReplace($x) {
  foreach ($RequestObj in $x){
  #$objSelection.find.replacement.Font.bold = $True
  $b = $objSelection.Find.Execute($($RequestObj.FIND), $MatchCase,
  $MatchWholeWord,$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,
  $MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,$Wrap,$Format,$($RequestObj.REPLACE),$ReplaceAll);
}
}

while ($objSelection.find.Font.italic = $True) {
$x = $FindItalic
 findAndReplace($x) 
 break
}

while ($objSelection.find.Font.bold = $True) {
$x = $FindBold
 findAndReplace($x)
 break
 }
 
$FileSaveAs ="D:\after.docx"
$wdFormatWordDefault = 16
$objDoc.SaveAs($FileSaveAs,$wdFormatWordDefault)<br>
```

But what I get is :
"One, *two_italic*, **three**."
It works for the italicized word "two", but not for the bolded word "three"...
 Why does the function stop halfway? Your help will be precious !

Comment: `=` is an **assignment**, not a comparison operator. replace `while ($objSelection.find.Font.italic = $True)` with `while ($objSelection.find.Font.italic)` (or append `-eq $true`. Same for the bold loop

Comment: @Theo. Thank you and sorry for my (too) late reaction. `while($objSelection.find.Font.italic)` (same for bold) gives me :  "One_bold_italic_bold, _two_bold_italic_bold,_ **three_bold_italic_bold.**"  Appending `-eq $true` results in : "One, _two_, **three**." (nothing changes). Confusing... any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Inserting `$objSelection.find.Font.bold = $False` in between the two while loops did the trick.
**New script** :

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("D:\before.docx")
$objWord.Visible = $true
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection

$Request = @"
FIND,REPLACE
"<[A-Za-z]*>", "^&_italic"
"<[A-Za-z]*>", "^&_bold"
"@ 

$RequestObjs = ConvertFrom-Csv $Request
$FindItalic = $RequestObjs[0]
$FindBold = $RequestObjs[1]

$ReplaceAll = 2
$FindContinue = 1
$MatchCase = $False
$MatchWholeWord = $True
$MatchWildcards = $True
$MatchSoundsLike = $False
$MatchAllWordForms = $False
$Forward = $True
$Wrap = $FindContinue
$Format = $True

function findAndReplace($x) {
  $b = $objSelection.Find.Execute($($x.FIND), $MatchCase,
  $MatchWholeWord,$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,
  $MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,$Wrap,$Format,$($x.REPLACE),$ReplaceAll);
 }
    
while ($objSelection.find.Font.bold = $True) {
$x = $FindBold
findAndReplace($x)
break
}

## KEY LINE ##
$objSelection.find.Font.bold = $False

while  ($objSelection.find.Font.italic =$True) {
$x = $FindItalic
findAndReplace($x) 
break
}
 
$FileSaveAs ="D:\after.docx"
$wdFormatWordDefault = 16
$objDoc.SaveAs($FileSaveAs,$wdFormatWordDefault)
```